# Arraylist of lat/long points of interest?

Tags: java, android

i've made an app that implements augmented reality based on POI's and have all the functionality working for one POI but i would now like to be able to put in multiple points. Can any give me advice on how to do this ? Can i create an array of POI's ?? posted my relevant code below but don't really know where to go from here.

```
private void setAugmentedRealityPoint() {
    homePoi = new AugmentedPOI(
            "Home",
            "Latitude, longitude",
            28.306802, -81.601358


    );
```

This is how its currently set and i then go on to use it in other area's as shown belown:

```
  public double calculateAngle() {
    double dX = homePoi.getPoiLatitude() - myLatitude;
    double dY = homePoi.getPoiLongitude() - myLongitude;
}
```

and here:

```
    private boolean isWithinDistance(double myLatitude, double myLongitude){

    Location my1 = new Location("One");
    my1.setLatitude(myLatitude);
    my1.setLongitude(myLongitude);

    Location target =new Location("Two");
    target.setLatitude(homePoi.getPoiLatitude());
    target.setLongitude(homePoi.getPoiLongitude());

    double range =my1.distanceTo(target);
    double zone = 20;
    if (range < zone ) {

        return true;

    }
    else {

        return false;

    }


}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `List<AugmentedPOI>` would be a good start

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ... beyond that: your question is answered in any good tutorial or book. You could start reading here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Using a List would be a smart idea. You could add all entries into it in code, or you could pull them in from a JSON file. When you're rendering them, you could check if they are in range.

If you have a lot of these POIs, you should divide them into smaller and smaller regions, and only load what you need. For example, structure them like this:

```
- CountryA
    + County 1
        * POI
        * POI
- CountryB
    + County 1
        * POI
        * POI
    + County 2
        * POI
```

Get the country and county of the user, and only load what you really need. I assume this is a multiplayer game, so I'll share some of my code.

On the server side, I have 3 objects: `Country`, `County` and `POI`.
First I discover all countries on the disk, and make an object for it. Inside my country object I have a list for all counties, and inside my County object I have a list of POIs. When a player joins, they send a packet with their Country and County, and I can select the appropriate POIs for them. Storing them in smaller regions is essential, or your server will have a hard time if you go through all of the POIs for every player.

Here is my method for discovering data: [Server.java#L311-L385](https://github.com/glorantq/PML-Server/blob/master/src/pml/server/Server.java#L311-L385)

Code for selecting POIs for a player: [Server.java#L139-L181](https://github.com/glorantq/PML-Server/blob/master/src/pml/server/Server.java#L139-L181)

And how you can render it: [PlayScreen.java#L209-L268](https://github.com/glorantq/VTM-Demo/blob/master/core/src/pml/test/game/screens/PlayScreen.java#L209-L268)

You need to port it to your own app, and I'm probably horrible at explaining, but I hope you got something out of it.